# gsutil rsync is killing my cable modem; looking for command line throttling

Tags: google-cloud-storage, osx-elcapitan, throttling, gsutil, trafficshaping

I have written bash scripts to sync files to Google Nearline buckets; this is raw photos and music, so many GB of files.  We run many devices, Netflix/Amazon streaming, gaming, phones, tablets, Skype, large and small downloads - all simultaneous without any problem for weeks.  Every time within a few minutes of starting gsutil rsync, my internet connection stops and I need to unplug my cable modem.  It is isolated to gsutil rsync, whether or not I use the -m switch.  This has been confirmed as the problem more than 20 times.

I have successfully used gsutil rsync when throttling from the "Network Link Conditioner" preference pane, but I don't want to throttle my entire system.  I am using El Capitan 10.11.3.  I've read several options like "trickle" even from Google's gsutil documentation, but the link is bad and I don't think it builds on current Mac OS.  I have a separate script that also worked using pfctl but I had to pass every possible Google IP range I could find, and the script only works if I'm root.

I'm looking for any way to solve this and I thought surely there would be an easier way to throttle a command line utility inside a bash script on Mac but I can't find one that works on El Capitan.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't have parallel composite uploads enabled, do you (parallel_composite_upload_threshold != 0)?  I'm surprised that a single stream upload is enough to kill your connection.  If you're downloading (bucket to local), in addition to not using the -m flag, you could turn off sliced downloads by setting sliced_object_download_threshold=0 in the GSUtil section of your .boto config file.  This will drop the parallelism during downloads from 4 threads to 1.

Comment: my ~/.boto file had this line commented; I've uncommented it so it is now parallel_composite_upload_threshold = 0; I'm not sure what the default would have been if this was commented

I'll see if this makes a difference on my next loads

Comment: The default is 0, so this won't have any impact.  So single-stream (one file at a time) uploads are killing your connection when using rsync?

Comment: I have multiple files needing uploaded after a photo shoot or after adding music.  Without the -m option, I think gsutil rsync uploads one file at a time, so yes.  Photo files alone are often 16MB or so, and maybe about 300MB to 600MB total.  Oddly enough, the cable modem is still accessible via browser, just my internet connection dies.  I'm currently trying a script to detect internet connectivity and a curl request to bounce the modem if it can't get out.  Modem is Motorola SB6120